# Convert Webcam Recorder Audio Into WMA

Tags: silverlight-4.0, audio, webcam, wma

I m working on recording audio from web cam.

So far i have successfully written the code for recording and saving audio to silverlights cache. My problem is i am not getting any way to convert that recorded audio files which are of unknown format into some know like wma.

Any direction to do this would be a great help for me.